# How do i automate scroll in chrome using AndroidDriver?

Tags: appium, appium-android

Trying to automate the hamburger menu in a android emulator on a pixel device. I am using Appium and automating with the android driver. I see that `scrollTo()` is deprecated does anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Just use this simple command for scrolling in appium using DesiredCapabilities in JAVA.

driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"***Your Text***\"));");

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

So the quick answer to this is, no there is no new way. This is to my understanding because UIAutomator2 does not allow elements that are not on the screen to be found by Appium's driver. UIAutomator2 is required for automating devices on Android version 7 and high I believe.

This means that there is no way to tell which direction the element is when it is off screen. So if anyone has a solution to this I'd be happy to hear it.

Now depending on what kind of app you are automating it is possible to fake swiping to an element if you know what direction it is in. For example if your app only scrolls up and down (like many apps) then as long as you know if the element is below or above your current position you can swipe to it. This can be done with a while loop:

```
while(elementNotFound) {
    if(findElement(byLocator)) {
        elementNotFound = !elementNotFound;
    }
    else {
        // This is where you would swipe in the direction of where the element is
    }

}
```

The new way of swiping is to use the `TouchAction` class. For example you can do:

```
(new TouchAction<>(driver)).press(PointOption.point(startX, position.startY)
                           .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
                           .moveTo(PointOption.point(endX, endY))
                           .release()
                           .perform();
```

Alternatively you can use the deprecated swipeTo method with UIAutomator drive type (not UIAutomator2). Again to my understanding this will only work for devices on lower Android SDK versions.

Sorry if this doesn't give you the answer you are looking for but hopefully it at least gives you a way to find your element.

Answer (score 0):

With latest Appium Java client 6.1.0, you can swipe using the following code,

```
new AndroidTouchAction (driver)
  .press (PointOption.point (startX, startY))
  .waitAction (WaitOptions.waitOptions (Duration.ofMillis (1000)))
  .moveTo (PointOption.point (endX, endY))
  .release ()
  .perform ();
```

Here `startX`, `startY`, `endX` and `endY` needs to be calculated as per your needs.

**OR**

You can even use my open source framework [Coteafs-Appium](https://github.com/WasiqB/coteafs-appium) v-3.0 to swipe like,

```
SliderActivity slide = new SliderActivity (this.androidDevice);
slide.onElement ("Slider")
  .swipe (SwipeDirection.RIGHT, SwipeStartPosition.LEFT, 75);
```

Comment: @Wasim Bhamla - Question summary says "Automate Scroll in Chrome" which means app under test is webview or mobile browser, does native library of Appium (AndroidTouchAction) work in webview context also ??

Comment: When working with Mobile browser, AndroidDriver refers to the browser and not the native app. So the driver will work similar to WebDriver and ideally AndroidTouchAction should also work.